# How can I deploy a telegram bot from intellij to heroku? I write the code using Java from a maven project

Tags: java, heroku, telegram-bot

I started coding a telegram bot using intellij idea. I wanted to deploy the bot using IntelliJ to my Heroku app. I created a heroku app and I wanted to deploy it from intelliJ and I tried to follow the instruction[From Here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-to-heroku-from-eclipse-or-intellij-idea), but it doesn't work for me. can You help doing this considering I'm an amateur programmer. Thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn't work? Where is the problem? Do you get an error during one of the steps?

Comment: @BeppeC The bot is not deployed... may be because it's not attached with the project I created in the heroku website... I've seen a video for eclipse and it uses SSH1 code to communicate with the app on heroku, bit there is no means here

Comment: added an answer to suggest what to do (use GitHub), I included suggestions for Python (because there is a very simple framework you can use) and for Java, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to deploy an Heroku application, if you are looking for something simple I would use GitHub as code repository then link it from Heroku.
Once this is done the deployment it is just a push of a button or you can also enable the automated option (each push to GitHub will deploy to Heroku).

If you develop a **Python** app you can use the very powerful [Python Telegram Bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot), you can follow the steps in their [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python) to deploy a Python application, in a nutshell:

- add requirements.txt to the root of your repository
- define Procfile in the root directory of your application
- bind the port provided by Heroku with the env variable $PORT

If you develop a **Java** application the concepts are similar, follow [Deploy Java Apps on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java), in a nutshell:

- use maven-dependency-plugin to create an Uber jar
- define Procfile in the root directory of your applicatio
- bind the port provided by Heroku with the env variable $PORT